# Calling SlidingMenu in another class

Tags: java, android

i have a noob problem (i think).
I using jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu - in Android Studio, everything works fine, but i have a small nooby problem.
I create my SlidngMenu object in onCreate method`

```
SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        menu.setShadowDrawable(null);
        menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu_frame);`
```

ListView fill and other actions are in fragmentActivity and this work fine, but i wan't to close menu onBackPressed:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    menu.showContent();
}
```

And this always give me a nullPointer error, what I do wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: Declare `SlidingMenu menu` before `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `menu` is a member variable, you are re-declaring `menu` again in onCreate. Instead just do like this,

`menu = new SlidingMenu(this);`

Comment: Many thanks! i daclare `public SlidingMenu menu;` and I call in onCreate `menu = new SlidingMenu(this);` and this works fine. Vary thanks for fast answer!